# Как преобразовать переменную типа string в тип array?

Tags: javascript

я отправляю запрос на сервер:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async:false,
  url: "http://###.ru/admin/db_connector.php",
  data: "",
  success: function(msg){
e.stores = msg;
  }
})
```

когда я консолю ответ вижу такое

```
console.log(e.stores)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно изменить код так чтобы в консоле было вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как это сделать?

Comment: `JSON.parse(msg)`

Comment: кнопка править находится под метками к вопросу: *поделиться* [*править*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/494559/edit) *тревога*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [*JSON.parse*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var arr = JSON.parse(e.stores)
```

В случае если возвращается не JSON, а кусок кода, возможно использовать функцию *eval*. Но при этом необходимо доверять месту, откуда получается данная информация.

```js
 var t = eval('[{name:"RB450g",price:"0",sales:0,rating:0},{name:"Rocket M2",price:"7600",sales:0,rating:0},{name:"Bullet 2 ",price:"1500",sales:0,rating:0},{name:"Герлен",price:"0",sales:0,rating:0}]');
 console.log(t);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35907/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy-----string---ar).

Answer (score 1):

А можно попробовать установить параметр `dataType: "json"`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  async:false,
  url: "http://###.ru/admin/db_connector.php",
  data: "",
  success: function(msg){
e.stores = msg;
  }
})
```

И на входе в функцию обработчик у вас уже будет объект.

Comment: не поможет, в комментариях перемещенных в чат, автор показывал как он посылаемую строку формирует